# Dx no classfiles specified Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik

I know this is a done to death topic, and I probably shouldn't be repeating it, but it is extremely annoying, because I've tried all the methods outlined before to resolve it and it still gives me an error.

I tried to clean the project, doesn't work
Tried to restart eclipse with -clean option, doesn't work
Tried to resintall eclipse - doesn't work
Tried to add a dummy reference and delete it, doesn't work

Everytime I do a clean and R.Java disappears I get an error saying no classfile found in gen/R.java then it automatically reappears and I get a conversion error.

I'm trying to fix something else which is troubling me and this error is just getting on my nerves because nothing I do works.

Does anyone have any alternate suggestions?

Can I just compile it like a normal java program and push it using adb.exe in the command prompt?

Comment: I have some problems like this, perhaps somehow they are similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866376/ant-build-failed-dx-no-classfiles-specified

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The fix: Go to project properties -> Android -> Change target to Android 2.2 (or older). Click apply and try to launch it again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. What I did was to clean the project and then use the option: Android tools ->fix project properties. That made my problem go away.